# How do I stop Audio/Video playback in a Modal with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, iframe, modal-dialog

I've been trying to figure out how to stop the audio from playing after closing a modal, and nothing seems to work.

### My attempt

```
<script>
var docReadyCodeForModal = setInterval(function() {
    if(jQuery) {
        clearInterval(docReadyCodeForModal);
       $("#myModal").modal('show');
       $("#stopClose").click(function(){
           $("#myModal").modal('pause');
    });
    }
}, 100);
</script>

<div aria-hidden="true" class="fade modal" id="myModal" style="display:none">
<div class="modal-lg modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">WELCOME TO THE THUNDERDOME!!!</h5>
<button id="stopClose" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">&times;</button></div>

<div class="modal-body">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item video-not-resize" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yGwjyodRst4?autoplay=1" title="YouTube video player"></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** video link removed for privacy reasons.

I appreciate any insight into this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Script to stop the video from playing when closing modal**

Add an id to your `iframe` and replace `#iframe-id` with that id.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var url = $("#iframe-id").attr('src');
            
        $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
            $("#iframe-id").attr('src', '');
        });
            
        $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
            $("#iframe-id").attr('src', url);
        });

});
```

You are using Bootstrap. This script listens to the Bootstrap events when hiding and showing the modal.

It removes the url from the `iframe` src attribute when closing modal and adds the url when the modal its opened.